# Initialize a field of an interface in JavaPoet

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

Is there any way to generate a field which looks like this:

```
public static final TableType<Character> NAMESPACE = new TableType<Character>() {};
```

I already generated this code:

```
  public static final TableType<Character> NAMESPACE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got. It's quite simple. There's an initialize method in TypeSpec.